# How to protect HTML5 canvas assets (images/audio)?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, drm, copy-protection, adobe-animate

I am creating a client software using Adobe Animate. The program runs on HTML5 canvas. The assets (image, audio files) are saved in the same folder as the HTML file.

When the software is distributed, it will be sent to the user to run locally on the machine.

The problem is users can take those assets. I want the user only run the HTML file but can not take the element assets for their own.

Technically, how to prevent or restrict users to take those?

Comment: Very simple - You can't

Comment: @AlonEitan How do other companies having HTML5 apps protect their products?